# Eloquent query builder - hasOne error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

This is driving me nuts. I have 2 tables;

1. explanations and
2. transactions.

In the models folder I have `transaction.php` and `explanation.php.`

transactions.php:

```
<?php

class Transaction extends Eloquent {

    public function explanation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Explanation');
    }

}
```

explanation.php

```
<?php

class Explanation extends Eloquent {



}
```

I'm simply calling

```
Transaction::find(18)->explanation()->first();
```

The error that I'm receiving is

> Method [hasone] is not defined on the Query class

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured this out, was reading the wrong documentation..

**Laravel 4.x**

```
$this->hasOne();
```

**Laravel < 4.x**

```
$this->has_one();
```